# How can I apply a background-size fix for IE without breaking links?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of links that all work on Chrome and Firefox but one of the links in IE is not clickable and does not link through the the url in the code. I now know that the cause is the background-size fix for IE. How can I apply the background-size fix without breaking the links?

HTML (the tierThreeCentre link is the one that is not working in IE):

```
<div class="tierThreeOrange">
    <h3>Header 1</h3>
    <a href="/home/" class="buttonLeft">Find out more</a>

</div>
<div class="tierThreeCentre"><!--this is the link not working in IE -->
    <h3>Header 2</h3>
    <a href="/home/next-page/" class="buttonLeft">Find out more</a>

</div>
<div class="tierThreeOrangeRight">
    <a href="http://promo.thissite.com" class="button">Find out more</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tierThree, .tierThreeOrange, .tierThreeCentre, {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:190px;
    height:150px;
    margin:20px 23px 20px 0px;
    padding:0;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #888686;
    -webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #888686;
    -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #888686;
}

.tierThree, .tierThreeOrange, .tierThreeBlack {
    background:url(/path/path2/images/hp/ah-t3l.png) no-repeat; 
    background-position: -49px -150px;
    background-size: 340px;
    background-position-x: -49px; /* IE fix */
    background-position-y: -150px /* IE fix */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/path/path2/images/hp/ah-t3l.png', sizingMethod='scale'); /* background-size fix for IE */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/path/path2/images/hp/ah-t3l.png',sizingMethod='scale')"; /* background-size fix for IE */
}

.tierThreeCentre {
    background:url(/path/path2/images/hp/ah-t3c.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:200px 150px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/path/path2/images/hp/ah-t3c.png', sizingMethod='scale'); /* background-size fix for IE */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='//path/path2/images/hp/ah-t3c.png',sizingMethod='scale')"; /* background-size fix for IE */
}
.tierThreeRight, .tierThreeOrangeRight,  {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:190px;
    height:150px;
    margin:20px 20px 20px 0px;
    padding:0;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #E0E0E0;
    -webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #E0E0E0;
    -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #E0E0E0;
}

.tierThreeRight, .tierThreeOrangeRight, .tierThreeBlackRight {
    background:url(/path/path2/images/hp/ah-t3r.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:-30px
}

.button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -8px 0px -1px #fe5715;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -8px 0px -1px #fe5715;
    box-shadow:inset 0px -8px 0px -1px #fe5715;
    background:#fe5715; /* Old browsers */
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffb260 0%, #fe5715 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffb260), color-stop(100%,#fe5715)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffb260 0%,#fe5715 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffb260 0%,#fe5715 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffb260 0%,#fe5715 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background:linear-gradient(top, #ffb260 0%,#fe5715 100%); /* W3C */
    _filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffb260', endColorstr='#fe5715',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 (underscrore hack for IE9) */
    -moz-border-radius:19px;
    -webkit-border-radius:19px;
    border-radius:19px;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px 17px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px -1px 0px #fe5715;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    bottom:15px;
}
.button:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -6px 0px -1px #fe7944;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -6px 0px -1px #fe7944;
    box-shadow:inset 0px -6px 0px -1px #fe7944;
    background:#fe7944; /* Old browsers */
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffc180 0%, #fe7944 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffc180), color-stop(100%,#fe7944)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffc180 0%,#fe7944 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffc180 0%,#fe7944 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffc180 0%,#fe7944 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background:linear-gradient(top, #ffc180 0%,#fe7944 100%); /* W3C */
    _filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffc180', endColorstr='#fe7944',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 (underscrore hack for IE9) */
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #fe5715;
    text-decoration:none
}

.buttonLeft {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -8px 0px -1px #fe5715;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -8px 0px -1px #fe5715;
    box-shadow:inset 0px -8px 0px -1px #fe5715;
    background:#fe5715; /* Old browsers */
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffb260 0%, #fe5715 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffb260), color-stop(100%,#fe5715)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffb260 0%,#fe5715 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffb260 0%,#fe5715 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffb260 0%,#fe5715 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background:linear-gradient(top, #ffb260 0%,#fe5715 100%); /* W3C */
    _filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffb260', endColorstr='#fe5715',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 (underscrore hack for IE9) */
    -moz-border-radius:19px;
    -webkit-border-radius:19px;
    border-radius:19px;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px 17px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px -1px 0px #fe5715;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    bottom:15px;
}
.buttonLeft:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -6px 0px -1px #fe7944;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -6px 0px -1px #fe7944;
    box-shadow:inset 0px -6px 0px -1px #fe7944;
    background:#fe7944; /* Old browsers */
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffc180 0%, #fe7944 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffc180), color-stop(100%,#fe7944)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffc180 0%,#fe7944 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffc180 0%,#fe7944 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffc180 0%,#fe7944 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background:linear-gradient(top, #ffc180 0%,#fe7944 100%); /* W3C */
    _filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffc180', endColorstr='#fe7944',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 (underscrore hack for IE9) */
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #fe5715;
    text-decoration:none
}
```

Comment: what is 'isn't working'?

Comment: @11684 the link is not clickable and does not link through the the url in the code (I've edited the question)

Answer (score 1):

Hey now give to anchor link display properties as like this

```
a.buttonLeft{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I will add the button code above - I should have included this

Comment: this didn't work unfortunately. I think it may have something to do with the background images